# sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" triggers "Creation of SecureRandom instance" in a "stateless" Spring Boot web app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, stateless

My Spring Boot web application is stateless.  In lieu of a session cookie, I create a JWT cookie upon authentication and check for it on each subsequent request. The implementation works.  For reference, in its custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class you find configuration like the following:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) // Disable the default session cookie; we'll be using a JWT authentication cookie instead.
                .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager())) // This filter intercepts the login, authenticates the user, and creates a JWT token in a cookie to authorize subsequent requests..
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) // This filter reads the JWT token from the cookie on subsequent requests, and authorizes the user (or not).
            .formLogin()
                .and()
    // etc...
```

I kept noticing a **WARN** in the logs when the user first accessed the homepage (or any page *except* the login page).

```
2020-02-13 09:15:34.697  WARN 7956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [541] milliseconds.
```

Since I don't have session IDs, I don't need this SecureRandom instance.  It looks like I'm also getting a new JSESSIONID cookie attached to the responses, too!  By selectively commenting stuff out, I discovered that the "sign out" button in the page footer is triggering the creation of a session.  Here's the culprit:

```
<footer>
    <form sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
    </form>
</footer>
```

Here's the question:  **How can I check, in my Thymeleaf templates, whether a user is authenticated, *without* triggering the accidental creation of a session?**  I want my 541 milliseconds back!

Comment: In the end, this seems to be a Tomcat thing, not a Spring Boot thing.  Not much chance of being able to disable it.